# Pass variable to background script and use it in other functions across tabs without using storage api

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension, background, webassembly

I am passing a string variable to the background script from a plugin(called from the popup.html).  I am receiving the string but I can't use my variable OUTSIDE of the listener function in the background script.

plugin.js:

```
chrome.runtime.sendMessage({'greeting': arbitraryString}, function(response) {});
```

background.js:

```
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(result) {
        alert("MESSAGE RECIEVED");
        alert("arbitraryString: " + result.greeting);
        var pw = result.greeting;
}
);

alert('var saved and is: ' + pw);
```

Everything works up to the last alert, because pw is undefined.

1. How do I pass the var from the listener function to live in the background script memory WITHOUT using storage api's so that the alert('var saved and is: ' + pw); is successful?
2. If successful, is pw available across all tabs for inject scripts?

Comment: For 1... Essentially I need to know how to generate the functional equivalent of a static variable inside the listener function.

Comment: 1) You need to declare the variable outside of the listener. If you want to persist the variable in the background script, you also need to mark the background script as persistent in the manifest: `"persistent": true`.
2) No, injected scripts (I assume you mean content scripts) live in its own JavaScript context, which is completely separate from extension pages (background, pup-up etc.). You will need to use message passing to communicate with the background script to get the value of your variable.

Comment: Thanks. It was a combination of 1. The persistent: true mark, which stops the unloading of background vars after 1 minute, 2.  the variable declaration, and 3. The fact that I was recalling the background script which unloads the memory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should declare pw outside of listener.

```
var pw;

chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(
    function(result) {
        alert("MESSAGE RECIEVED");
        alert("arbitraryString: " + result.greeting);
        pw = result.greeting;
    }
);
```

Comment: That makes sense, but I tried it and it is still undefined outside of the listener.

Comment: Well it means that the code that reads this variable is executed before any message is received by the script. By the way, are those messages JS objects? I believe they are sent as strings and you have to JSON.stringify/parse them. Correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Well, yes, on the first call it may be executed before being received, but on subsequent calls of background.js it should be defined right?

Comment: As for the messages, the string is coming through correctly without parsing and reads off fine in the alert (inside the listener function).

Comment: Essentially I need the equivalent of a static variable generated inside the listener function.

Comment: Don't know if background.js allows such a thing. Maybe you should try another way? LocalStorage (just guessing)?

Comment: It works with local storage, but I wanted to get around that.

Comment: Ah. I found my problem. Stupid mistake. I was calling the background script every time I wanted the variable. This obviously unloads the memory. However, your recommendation of declaring outside the variable was also a good reminder. Thanks. In addition, the suggestion in the comments on the OP of declaring persistent: true in the manifest allows the variable to persist longer than 1 minute. I'll go ahead and mark this accepted.